# Convert type int to a string of the name of a const when marshaling to JSON

Tags: go

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
type Type int

const (
    A Type = iota
    B
    C
)

type Character struct {
    Type Type   `json:"type"`
}
```

When I call `json.Marshal(...)` on the struct, is there a way that the `json:"type"` representation is a string called either `"A"`, `"B"`, or "`C`"?

When this is presented in JSON, nobody is going to know what `0`, `1`, or `2` is, so the name of the constant is more useful.

Apologies if this has been asked before. I googled all over and couldn't find anything.

Here is an example:

```
type Type int

const (
    A Type = iota
    B
    C
)

type Character struct {
    Type Type   `json:"type,string"`
}

func main() {
    c := Character{}
    c.Type = A
    j, err := json.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```

I want `fmt.Println(string(j))` to print `{"type":"A"}`, not `{"type":0}`.

Comment: Please clarify the question by recreating the issue with minimal code.

Comment: The most common way to do this is implement `encoding.TextMarshaler` and `encoding.TextUnmarshaler`. You can probably find a program that you can invoke via go generate to do this semi-automatically.

Comment: I just edited my existing post.

Comment: Unless your type of A is an int the value is also an int. You could check in your code `j == A`. Another way is that you make your `type Type string`.

Comment: I would also recomend not to use the name `Type` because you can mix that with the keyword `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a custom marshaller for your type.

```
type Type int

const (
    A Type = iota
    B
    C
)

var typeToString = map[Type]string{
    A: "A",
    B: "B",
    C: "C",
}

func (t Type) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(typeToString[t])
}

type Character struct {
    Type Type `json:"type"`
}

func main() {
    c := Character{}
    c.Type = A
    j, err := json.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```

The function `MarshalJSON` defines how `json.Marshal` should marshal your type. You can do something similar for unmarshaling if you need to go the other direction as well.

See https://play.golang.org/p/mLxThWA19by.

Comment: In this case a slice would suffice and be more efficient. An array might be even better.

Answer (score 1):

Short reply: there's NO direct option to achieve your goal.

Long reply: truth is, you can actually override the way Go can encode structs.

Here's the working code:

https://play.golang.org/p/i92pUpNG-Wr

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// please consider to rename this!
type Type int

const (
    A Type = iota
    B
    C
)

type Character struct {
    Type Type `json:"-"`
}

func (c *Character) mapTypeToString() string {
    switch c.Type {
    case B:
        return "B"
    case C:
        return "C"
    }

    // defaults on A
    return "A"
}

// MarshalJSON overwrites the standard JSON marshal.
func (c *Character) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Type string `json:"type"`
    }{
        Type: c.mapTypeToString(),
    })
}

func main() {
    c := &Character{}
    c.Type = A
    j, err := json.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```

Be aware of the `c := &Character{}` initialization.

The tradeoff would be to have the `mapTypeToString()` method that needs to be updated according to the different types of ... Type.

Please, also consider to avoid naming structs and vars like `Type` :)

Answer (score 0):

So your JSON API gives you the type A:

> I want fmt.Println(string(j)) to print {"type":"A"}, not {"type":0}.

You could change your code like this, then your API works:

https://play.golang.org/p/ypvFvQpBw-C

```
type JSONType string

const (
    A JSONType = "A"
    B JSONType = "B"
    C JSONType = "C"
)

type Character struct {
    JSONType JSONType `json:"type,string"`
}

func main() {
    c := Character{}
    c.JSONType = A
    j, err := json.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```

Comment: I personaly would not write the code like this, but I wanted to be as close to the given example.

Comment: Yeah, the idea is that I'm storing integers in the database and not strings.

Comment: Then you need to map the integers to strings, because the JSON includes strings and not integers.